# Session timeout for login page

Tags: php, session, session-timeout

Suppose I have one login form in php and I set session on `user_id` and `user_name`. Now, as per my php knowledge the default session timeout is 24mins, and suppose I'm using this application for whole day. Then obviously after each 24 mins my application will be logged out and I require to login again BUT still I'm able to use it continuously. HOW?

Dear friends don't laugh, I'm new in this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default session timeout is indeed 24 minutes. This means however that an user is going to lose his session when the user doesn't interact with the application for 24 minutes (inactivity). You can change the session timeout in php.ini, search for: `session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440` (1440 seconds = 24 minutes), or directly in the php code `ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 1440);`

Comment: it means if I logged in and then I went to take a bath for 50 mins and come to see my application then I require login again, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// 24 minutes in seconds
$time= 2880;
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $time); // set the session max lifetime to 24 minutes

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['my_session']) && (time() - $_SESSION['my_session'] > $time))
{
    // last request was more than 24 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for this page
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data
}
$_SESSION['my_session'] = time(); // Update session
```